# for what reason do i keep getting "bsd syntax error" when i run ps -f in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ps

so,  i'm a beginner to Shell, i need to write a script that, given a numeric argument, will display info about the processes with the entered numbers (by user ofc), given a non numeric argument, if it's "--help" it will display help (which i really don't know how to do), and if it's something else, it gives info about processes having that argument as names ( for ex, "./script bash" will display info about the bash process) , here is what i've done so far:

```
 #!/bin/sh
case $arg in
          $num )

               a=""
               for arg in $@
               do
          a="${a} $arg"
              done 

             printf "$(ps -f ${a})\n"
             ;; 
           *)
            p=$(pidof ${arg})
            printf "$(ps -f ${p})"
            ;;
         esac
```

so, the numeric argument part works, but the other one doesn't, whenever i enter a non numeric name i get that "BSD syntax" error message and i really don't know what to do.
thank you to everyone willing to help me out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the _exact_ error message you are receiving, along with the _exact_ command you ran to get that (paste the text, don't take a screenshot). There may be details there which mean nothing to you, but which someone can explain to you.

Comment: just `ps -f "$@"` No need for a loop Do not do `printf "$(suff)"` just `stuff`, it already outputs the data. `case $arg in
          $num` `arg` and `num` are not set.

Comment: Please indent your code in a meaningful way.